# Organize LabVIEW in a git repository

Tags: windows, git, labview

I'm forced to work with LabVIEW source code on a Windows 7 machine and am curious what might be the best setup to handle the source code in a remote Git repository.

Currently I'm handling everythin like I would with my C projects, means Git Bash and a simple .gitignore file that excludes .aliases and .lvlps files, but think that there might be some possible improvement.

Thanks for every suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have LV professional you can get diff and merge to work using

https://github.com/joerg/LabViewGitEnv

I use this together with git bash.

Comment: Please include some more info into your answer. How to use the program behind your link? How will it help OP to solve his problem? Simply pasting a link doesn't help future users, if the link only leads to a 404-page.

Answer (score 5):

You could look for tips and ideas in the NI Community Group set up just for Git users.

https://decibel.ni.com/content/groups/git-user-group?view=blog

Answer (score 0):

Well, what answers do you expect?

If you are searching for another git client, i can recommend you [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/). Im working with [Egit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/), but thats only for eclipse. Im sure there are a bunch of clients out there, just google it.

Other than that, Git Bash is fine. It works, why change it? Using another client won't give you any benefits other than better UI's.

Comment: I'm more curious about things like: how to organize a big project, what files types end up in your .gitignore, how do you merge e.g. compare revisions. Stuff like that.